# How to get the remaining left space using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to calculate the width of an element depending on left space remaining.
Right now I am calculating this using `width: calc(100% - 419px);` ,but I want the with to be calculated dynamic depending on remaining left space.

Comment: What have you done so far in jQuery/JS?

Comment: I didn't used any jQuery/JS code for this because it wasn't necessary

Comment: Well then why are you asking how to do it using jQuery?

Comment: Because I need this element to have a dynamic width depending on the left space remaining on it's left side. There are also another 2 elements that don't have a fixed width, and when these 2 elements are getting bigger, the things are being messed up. So my element should get his width depending on the other 2 elements width.

Comment: Right. So, what have you done so far to solve this issue, in jQuery/JS?

Comment: Nothing, because I don't know what it needs to be done...I was thinking that maybe there is a function that returns the remaining space

Comment: Questions must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

set `overflow:hidden` for that block and it start trying to fit the empty space.